# Converting UTC to local

Tags: c++, visual-c++, time, utc

My timezone is United States Eastern Standard Time which is 5 hours behind UTC. Given that:

```
struct tm t = { 0, 30, 15, 10, 3, 112, 0, 0, -1 };
time_t utc_in_timet = _mkgmtime(&t);

struct tm tt = { 0 };
localtime_s(&tt, &utc_in_timet);
```

tt is off by one hour when localtime_s returns. I have 11:30 in there instead of 10:30.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code in my machine and it works correctly (my time zone is GMT+2). Since you are telling your system to check for daylight savings itself (the last parameter for the `tm` is `-1`), it is actually using EDT and is thus giving you GMT-4.

You can try replacing the month (`3`) with `2`, so that the date would be March 10th, just before the daylight savings change; I bet you will get the expected 10:30 in that case.

Comment: I just noticed that too. Setting tm_isdst to 1 will pretty much have the same effect, right?

Comment: There must be some generic way to convert UTC to local time by taking daylight savings in to effect, right?

Comment: Yes, setting `tm_isdst` to `1` would have the same effect in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I think it has something to do with daylight saving time. Are you sure your timezone currently is EST (-5) ? Because it seems your system should be using EDT (-4) ?

Comment: my timezone is most definitely set to EST. Besides this code is off by an hour even when a colleague tried it in UK. I believe it returned 16:30 when localtime_s returned (or 14:30 -- I can't remember which)

Comment: Well, I also tried this: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html When I convert to EST-New York, it automatically uses daylight saving. I also gives this warning for EST: `Only some locations are currently on EST, because most places there are currently on Daylight Saving Time.` So I really think the timezone you are using is EST with daylight saving (=EDT)

Answer (score 1):

Verify your local timezone.  Both England (e.g. London) and the east coast of the U.S. are currently in daylight savings time so this looks to be the issue (as someone already mentioned).  For the U.S. east coast EDT would be 4 hours different.

Answer (score 0):

Thought the problem is the month is March: struct tm t = { 0, 30, 15, 10, **3**, 112, 0, 0, -1 };
Then, it is daylight saving time issue. But as pointed below by Gorpik "months go from 0 to 11, so April is indeed 3".

So, i checked - it shows 18:30 in Haifa which is correct +2UTC.

Comment: This is wrong. In `tm`, months go from 0 to 11, so April is indeed `3`.

Comment: Yes, just wanted to delete post. But you type faster.